# JavaScript clearTimeout

Tags: redirect, settimeout

OK.. If the user takes any action, I have to clear the setTimeout and I DO NOT want it to go ahead and redirect to Google.  But it is not working..  Can someone please look at this?

```
script type="text/javascript">

function redirect() {
    window.location = "https://google.com";
 }

var timer = window.setTimeout("redirect()", 8000);
var capital = window.prompt("MY Question?","");

if(capital != null && capital.length < 1)  {
clearTimeout(timer);
document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML="Sorry.<br /> The answer is.";
 }
else {
if(window.confirm("Is that your final answer?")){ 

 document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML = "The answer to the question is: " + capital + ", so says you.";}
else{
var capital = window.prompt("What is the capital of Missouri?","");
 document.getElementById("firstdiv").innerHTML = "The answer to the question is: " + capital + ", so says you.";}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the ID of the timer to `clearTimeout`:

```
clearTimeout(timer);
```

Also, don't pass a string to `setTimeout`. Pass a function:

```
var timer = window.setTimeout(redirect, 8000);
// Or
var timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
    redirect();
}, 8000);
```